# What html5 tag should I use inside a figure tag

Tags: html

The figure tag displays a vertical 2d bar displaying certain values for sales.
the figcaption tag displays the label "Sales".

What html5 tag for the divs inside the figure should I use?

```
<figure>
        <div class="push-center roundedArea" style="background-color:#fff;height:22%;"></div>
        <div class="push-center diagram" style="background-color:#ff99cc;height:11%;">3</div>
        <div class="push-center diagram" style="background-color:#ff33cc;height:44%;">44</div>
        <div class="push-center diagram" style="background-color:#ff66cc;height:23%;">36</div> 
    </figure>
<figcaption>
  Sales
</figcaption>
```

Comment: The [W3C Wiki `figure` article](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/figure) explains some of the semantic uses of it, which are varied. The [`figure` spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element) says that it should contain "flow content" with an optional `figcaption` element before or after the flow content. Flow content is basically anything on [this list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1). TL;DR: You can put a lot of stuff in there, just make sure it makes semantic sense. Also, `div` elements are allowed inside `figure` elements.

Comment: yes I saw div-tag is among the flow content tags, thanks :) Put it in a solution?

Comment: Posted as an answer :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [MDN `figure` article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) explains some of the semantic uses of it, which are varied. The [`figure` spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element) says that it should contain "flow content" with an optional `figcaption` element before or after the flow content. Flow content is basically anything on [this list](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#flow-content).

TL;DR: You can put a lot of stuff in there, just make sure it makes semantic sense.

Also, `div` elements are allowed inside `figure` elements (see the list in the above link).

Comment: Despite that your answer is correct I have realized that I use the figcaption in a wrong way. w3c says the figure contains a figcaption but my figcaption is outside the figure. Hm... that is pretty stupid. I can not change that it would cause technical display problems...

Comment: @HelloWorld I saw that you had put `figcaption` outside of the `figure`. Note that `figure` doesn't need a `figcaption`. I looked at the [`figcaption` spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figcaption-element), and it says that it represents the "contents of the figcaption element's parent figure element, *if any*" (emphasis mine). The "if any" part implies to me that a `figcaption` is allowed outside of a `figure` element, but that it may not have much meaning in that case. So it is technically correct, but perhaps not semantically correct to have it outside of `figure`.

Comment: ahh well when I use the figure and I have a label with a meaning for every element within the figure I want to use a figcaption and I thin nk that is correct actually even a must I think to be 100% semantically correct :)